# vector not pushing back vector (C++)

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, fopen, scanf

I'm trying to read a file and assigning the contents of the file into a vector of vectors(matrix).
Problem is that it doesn't seem to do what I need it to.
I'm also not too familiar with vectors so please excuse any obvious mistakes :P

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

void readfile(const char* filename,
    std::vector< std::vector<float> >& output)
{
    std::vector<float> vec123(3);
    char buff[80];
    FILE* myfile;
    myfile = fopen(filename, "r");

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), myfile) != NULL) {
        sscanf(buff, "%f %f %f", vec123[0], vec123[1], vec123[2]);
        output.push_back(vec123);
    }
    fclose(myfile);
}
```

Here is my main:

```
int main() //yes, stdio.h, vector, "readfile" and string were included
{
    std::vector< std::vector<float> > myvec;
    readfile("myfile.txt", myvec); //file exists in my folder, valid
    printf("%f\n", myvec[2][2]);   //valid numbers for the file I'm reading
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that if it didn't assign anything to myvec, the printf would segfault, but it does seem to assign myvec something since it prints out a float of zeroes no matter what valid object I request from it. I know an easy way to do this without the 2D vector hassle, but sadly my math libraries are optimised for matrices.
myfile contains something like "2.2 3.14159 1.0 newline 9.3 2.2 2.2 newline ..."

Comment: Why do you use `stdio.h` and `string.h` in `c++`?

Comment: Rather than using `char[]`, `sscanf`, etc, I'd recommend using [streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138785/c-reading-file-into-vector), it's much cleaner and safer.

Comment: @Cyber I might try to, if that is the problem. fopen seemed like a better solution than things such as ofstream.

Comment: As you see from user2040251's answer c-like functions are worsh for beginners. If you use streams, you wouldn't make mistakes like you did

Comment: You need to debug your application, instead of guessing.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
sscanf(buff, "%f %f %f", &vec123[0], &vec123[1], &vec123[2]);
```

Because `sscanf` takes a pointer as a parameter.

Comment: Ah, forgot they were floats, not char*s. Though, even if I changed my code, it still didn't assign the correct parameters from my file to my vector