# Copying binary file content to vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, binaryfiles

I am trying to copy the contents of the binary file whose path I have specified in the code to a vector using the methods in the link, but I am getting the error in the line I added as a comment line. how can i solve this error or which method is best for me?

Link: https://sites.google.com/site/hashemian/home/tips-and-tricks/copy-array-cpp

```
    void MainWindow::on_horizontalScrollBar_actionTriggered(int action)
   {
   QFile read_data("C:/Users/cats_user/Desktop/00000000.log");
   char file_data;
   QByteArray fullContent;

   if(!read_data.open(QFile::ReadOnly)){
       return;
   }

   while(!read_data.atEnd()){
   read_data.read(& file_data, sizeof(char));
   fullContent.append((file_data));
   }

   std::vector<char>theVector;
   int n =sizeof (fullContent)/sizeof (char);
   theVector.insert(theVector.end(), fullContent, fullContent+n); // 'operator int' is a private member of QByteArray note: declared private here

   }
```

Comment: `fullContent, fullContent+n` whats that? You seem to think `QByteArray` is just a pointer, but it is not

Comment: `int n =sizeof (fullContent)/sizeof (char);` -- I don't use `qt` and I know that this will not do what you think it does.  Print out the value of `sizeof(fullContent)`.

Comment: if the site you copied the code from had used `std::begin(fullContent)` and `std::end(fullContent)` it would work. The site is providing poor / outdated advice. Nowadays you never need `sizeof` to get the size of an array

Comment: Why do you use the temporary `fullContent` to begin with, instead of adding directly to the vector?

Comment: Also if you have raw binary data you should probably be using `unsigned char` (or `std::byte` or `std::uint8_t`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude QByteArray is a wrapper around a an array of `char`

Comment: And there are ways to get the size of the file. With that you could resize the vector to the correct size, and read everything all at once directly into the vector.

Comment: Really sorry, but you became a victim of [cargo-cult-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Don't use code from some online sites without understanding in-depth (!) what it actually does and why it does things the way it does.

Comment: @Caleth So is `std::vector<char>` basically. I still don't see the need for `fullContent`. To be honest, I don't see the need for the vector either since the OP doesn't tell us what it's for. Perhaps the `QByteArray` could be enough for the OP's real needs?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude exactly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file into vector in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138785/how-to-read-a-file-into-vector-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The site you are copying from is teaching you how to copy from a C style array. [`QByteArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbytearray.html) is already a class similar to `std::vector`, and it interoperates with `std::vector` in the normal manner.

```
void MainWindow::on_horizontalScrollBar_actionTriggered(int action)
{
    QFile read_data("C:/Users/cats_user/Desktop/00000000.log");
    QByteArray fullContent = read_data.readAll();
    std::vector<char> theVector(fullContent.begin(), fullContent.end());     
}
```

You only need to copy it into a vector if you are calling code expecting exactly `std::vector<char>`. If the code you are calling is generic, it can use `QByteArray`, as that has the same members as `std::vector<char>` with the same meanings.

As an alternative, you could read into the vector directly.

```
void MainWindow::on_horizontalScrollBar_actionTriggered(int action)
{
    std::fstream read_data("C:/Users/cats_user/Desktop/00000000.log", std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::binary);
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> first = read_data, last;
    std::vector<char> theVector(first, last);     
}
```

Comment: The file whose path I specified is binary file. I tried the examples you gave, but I could not read the content as binary.

Comment: @SühaAydın you may need to pass `std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::binary` as the mode parameter of the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream)