# C++. how to read from file and match with input

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am trying to read a textfile and matching the fruit to what I have type(e.g I type apple and it will search the textfile for the word apple and match it and output that it's been found) but I am struggling to achieve the results I wanted and thus need help in it.

I have a text file (fruit.txt) with contents shown below

apple,30

banana,20

pear,10

---

this is my code

```
string fruit;
string amount;
string line = " ";
ifstream readFile("fruit.txt");
fstream fin;

cout << "Enter A fruit: ";
cin >> fruit;

fin >> fruit >> amount;
while (getline(readFile, line,','))
    {
        if(fruit != line) {
            cout <<"the fruit that you type is not found.";
        }

       else {
           cout <<"fruit found! "<< fruit;
       }
}
```

please advise 
thanks.

Comment: What's the problem are you facing?

Comment: What went wrong exactly?

Comment: Look at serialization / deserialization .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415850/c-how-serialize-deserialize-objects-without-any-library

Comment: Visual Studio has a superb debugger. Just Press `Step into (F11)` and you'll see the magic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop with `getline` you read `"apple"` into `line` the first loop, and `"30\nbanana"` into `line` the second time, etc.

Instead read the whole line (using `getline`), and then use e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to extract the fruit and amount.

Something like:

```
std::string line;
while (std:::getline(readFile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::string fruit;
    if (std::getline(iss, fruit, ','))
    {
        // Have a fruit, get amount
        int amount;
        if (iss >> amount)
        {
            // Have both fruit and amount
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will start by saying that I am just a beginner like you, took your code and made some changes, for example:

1. Used "fstream" to read from file until is not the end of the file.
2. Then reading each line into a stringstream so I can brake it later using the coma delimiter.
3. I've also used a two dimension array to store the fruits and the amount of each type.
4. In the end I had to search through the array for the fruit I wanted to display.

Before I post the code I want to warn you that the program wont work if there are more then 20 fruits with more than one property (in this case the amount).
Here's the code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void main  (void)
{
    fstream readFile("fruit.txt");
    string fruit,amount,line;
    bool found = false;
    string fruitArray[20][2];

    cout << "Enter A fruit: ";
    cin >> fruit;

    while (!readFile.eof())
    {
        int y =0 ;
        int x =0 ;
        getline(readFile,line);
        stringstream ss(line);
        string tempFruit;
        while (getline(ss,tempFruit,','))
        {
            fruitArray[x][y] = tempFruit;
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++)
        {
            string test = fruitArray[i][ii] ;
            if  (test == fruit)
            { 
                amount = fruitArray[i][ii+1];
                found = true;
                break;
            } 
            else{
                cout <<"Searching" << '\n';
            } 
        }
        if (found){
            cout << "Found: " << fruit << ". Amount:" << amount << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Press any key to exit he program.";
    getchar();
}
```

Hope you've learned something from it ( I sure did).